# Partition function in spherical coordinates

Tags: statistical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, partition-function

Suppose I write the Hamiltonian/energy of my system in spherical coordinates ($r,\theta,\varphi$) with conjugated momentums($p_r,p_\theta,p_\varphi$).

How do I calculate the partition function?

If

$$Z=\int e^{-\beta H}d^3r\;d^3p=\int e^{-\beta H}r^2\sin(\theta)J(p_r,p_\theta,p_\varphi)drd\theta d\varphi\;dp_rdp_\theta dp_\varphi,$$

what should $J$ be?

Edit: to add to my question, I tried to write the momentums as functions of $p_x,p_y,p_z$ (and thus as a function of $x,y,z$ also) but it is a mess and I do not think that's the good approach.

Comment: Do you have a guess as to what $J$ might be?

Comment: @jacob1729 To me it is 1, but I do not know why.

Comment: sorry I initially misread this (thought you were imposing spherical polars on $p$ space). I suspect the answer is to consider the change of variables as a canonical transform, but am not actually that sure.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136966/calculation-of-the-partition-function-for-a-classical-2d-gas-lying-on-the-surfac). Liouville’s theorem preserves phase space volumes under canonical transformations.

Comment: https://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/cartesian-to-spherical-change-of-variables-in-3d-phase-space/      Might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll spare you the cotangent bundles and differential geometrese and just summarize the takeaway that, in fact, $J=1/r^2 \sin \theta$ so that the *entire*  phase-space Jacobian is 1,
$$
dx dy dz ~ dp_x dp_y dp_z = dr d\theta d\phi ~dp_r dp_\theta dp_\phi  .
$$

A direct (blood, sweat and tears) derivation is available in Peter Joot's [Blog](https://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/cartesian-to-spherical-change-of-variables-in-3d-phase-space/).

The reason is that Cartesian to spherical is a point canonical transformation, so it preserves phase-space volumes (Liouville's theorem―which also holds for motion, since *that* is also a canonical transformation generated by the Hamiltonian).

To rationalize this, consider a free particle of mass *m* =1. The Hamiltonian is then $\vec p ^2/2$, generating 
$$
\frac{d\vec r}{dt} = \{\vec r , \vec p ^2  \}/2 = \vec p.
$$
It is simple in Cartesian coordinates, but in spherical coordinates, 
[given the line element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) 
$$
d\vec r= \hat r ~ dr +\hat \theta ~ r d\theta + \hat \phi ~ r \sin\theta d\phi,
$$
you have
$$
\dot{\vec r}= \hat r ~ \dot{r} +\hat \theta ~ r \dot{\theta} + \hat \phi ~ r \sin\theta  ~\dot{\phi} \\
=\vec p=     \hat r ~  p_r +\hat \theta ~ \frac{1}{r} p_\theta + \hat \phi ~\frac{1}{ r \sin\theta}  p_\phi ~~.
$$

These are the canonical conjugate momenta gotten from the canonical procedure and, e.g., $p_\phi$ is not the projection of $\vec p$ in the direction $\phi$!

You've seen this covariant bit before in the gradient expressed in spherical coordinates,
$$
\nabla =   \hat r ~  \partial_r +\hat \theta ~ \frac{1}{r} \partial_\theta + \hat \phi ~\frac{1}{ r \sin\theta}  \partial_\phi ,
$$
not coincidentally, as it is proportional to the quantization of the momentum when you transcend classical mechanics.

Twice the Hamiltonian is, in this language,
$$
2H= \vec p^2 = p_r^2 + \frac{p_\theta^2}{r^2}  + \frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2\sin^2\theta },
$$
(and the Liouville one-form would be $\vec p \cdot d\vec r = p_r dr + p_\theta d\theta +p_\phi d\phi $.  In components, $p_r=\dot{r}, \quad p_\theta /r = r \dot{\theta}, \quad p_\phi/ r \sin\theta= r\sin \theta ~ \dot{\phi}  $. )

The volume element in phase space, then,  by above, is 
$$
d^3 \vec r ~ d^3 \vec p= r^2 \sin \theta ~ dr d\theta d\phi  ~ \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta} dp_r  dp_\theta dp_\phi, 
$$
collapsing to the top line.